# How to use hasMany() method with composite foreign key?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following structure:

[image]

branch_has_language table represents the ManyToMany relationship between the languages and branches. On the other hand a product belongs to a branch_has_language record. So the  product can be created for specific language and branch, where they 'exist' together in branch_has_language table.

My question is how to create the model in order to represent this relationship. Currently I have the following models:

Branch model

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    protected $table = "branches";

    public function languages()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany("\App\Language", "branch_has_language");
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("\App\User", "branch_has_user");
    } 

    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof Language) {
            return new BranchLanguage($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Language model

```
class Language extends Model
{
    protected $table = "languages";

    public function branches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("\App\Branch", 'branch_has_language');
    }

    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof Branch) {
            return new BranchLanguage($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

BranchLanguage pivot model

```
class BranchLanguage extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'branch_has_language';

    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Branch");
    }

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Language");
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("\App\Product");
    }

    public function systems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("\App\System");
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("\App\Item");
    }
}
```

However when I want to make a call to `products()` method in `BranchLanguage` class, I got an error saying `"Column products.branch_id does not exists"`. This is correct. I need to specify the foreign key in the `hasMany()` method. However my foreign key is composite.

`branch_has_language_branch_id` and `branch_has_language_language_id` columns build up the foreign key. Therefore I could not define it in the `hasMany()` method.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a table reference a foreign `id` it belongs to it, otherwise it has it. In Language and Branch models the methods related to the pivot should be referenced as `hasMany()`.

Anyway I don't get why would you complicate it this way, this could just be a classic many to many with a name of `branch_language`. Laravel understands itself that it is a many to many if you call it with singular version of the table names joined by `_` and alphabetically ordered.

Then in the products table's migration you reference it with the name you want as a foreign of the pivot table.

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('branch_language_id');
$table->foreign('branch_language_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('branch_language')
    ->onDelete('restrict'); // not necessary
```

Comment: You are right. My mind was too much in Laravel and couldn't realise that the 'mistake' is in the database schema. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to me too all the time, don't worry =]

Answer (score 0):

Is this not a has many through relation?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

You can define local key, foreign key and table names in the hasMany* methods.

Regards

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this is not helping me because I have two tables on the left side. How would you implement the method in my situation?

Comment: It is not, actually. You have a through relation when you have to reference a column that belongs to a table that belongs to another table. Like `cities`->`provinces`->`regions`->`nations`.